# Nullable field in CTE is varchar, get Error converting data type varchar to numeric when joining to CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, nullable, common-table-expression

Any suggestions? The code below works if I comment out the column `intv.PAIN_INTERVENTION` below.

No matter what I do to cast `intv.PAIN_INTERVENTION` as `varchar`, I keep getting this error message when I join the CTE:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 7
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Code:

```
,pain_intervention_cte AS ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ACCOUNT_NUM, PAIN_INTERVENTION
    FROM 
        INIT_CTE
    INNER JOIN ....
)

,pain_intervention_cte1 AS ( 
    select  
        ACCOUNT_NUM as ACCOUNT_NUM, 
        CAST(PAIN_INTERVENTION AS varchar) AS PAIN_INTERVENTION 
    from 
        pain_intervention_cte 
    where 
        PAIN_INTERVENTION is not null
    UNION 
    select  
        ACCOUNT_NUM as ACCOUNT_NUM,
        CAST(PAIN_INTERVENTION AS varchar) AS PAIN_INTERVENTION 
    from 
        pain_intervention_cte 
    where 
        PAIN_INTERVENTION is null
)
select DISTINCT 
    INIT_CTE.*, intv.PAIN_INTERVENTION
from 
    init_cte
left outer join 
    pain_intervention_cte1 INTV ON intv.ACCOUNT_NUM =  init_cte.ACCOUNT_NUM
```

Comment: What are the columns in `INIT_CTE.*` ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying to cast pain_intervention as a numeric type to avoid this? What type of data does it hold?

Comment: The error is not in the code that you are showing, because there is no place where that column would be converted to a numeric value.  What is on line 7 and on the preceding lines?

Comment: What is the datatype of ACCOUNT_NUM in all the tables where it appears?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Thanks for everyone's feedback. PAIN_INTERVENTION is varchar and ACCOUNT_NUM is numeric. Can the nullable fields from these CTEs be cast to numeric, even with text in the columns?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
,pain_intervention_cte AS ( 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CAST(isnull(ACCOUNT_NUM,0) AS int) AS ACCOUNT_NUM, CAST(isnull(PAIN_INTERVENTION,0) AS varchar) AS PAIN_INTERVENTION 
FROM 
    INIT_CTE
INNER JOIN ....
)

,pain_intervention_cte1 AS ( 
select  
    ACCOUNT_NUM, PAIN_INTERVENTION 
from 
    pain_intervention_cte 
where 
    PAIN_INTERVENTION is not null
UNION 
select  
    ACCOUNT_NUM, PAIN_INTERVENTION 
from 
    pain_intervention_cte 
where 
    PAIN_INTERVENTION is null
)
select DISTINCT 
    INIT_CTE.*, intv.PAIN_INTERVENTION
from 
    init_cte
left outer join 
pain_intervention_cte1 INTV ON intv.ACCOUNT_NUM =  init_cte.ACCOUNT_NUM
```